# How to get the selected data in a table format?

Tags: asp.net-ajax

HTML Part

```
<div class="container">
    <select id="drop1" onchange="funDivision()">
    </select>
    <select id="drop2" onchange="funDivision2()"></select>
    <select id="drop3" onchange="funDivision3()"></select>
    <select id="drop4"></select>
</div>
```

I have four select dropdown where each dropdown data are based upon the previous select option. At the end of the select option, I want to display all the selected value to be displayed in a table format. How can I achieve this?

```
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var arr = new Array();
        var i = 0;
        $(document).ready(function () {
            ajaxLoadDropDown('#drop1', '/Home/Division/');
        });

        function ajaxLoadDropDown(id, url, df) {
            df = df || "";
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                var v = "<option>---Select---</option>";
                $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                    v += "<option value='" + value + "' >" + value + "</option>";
                });
                $(id).html(v);
            });
        }

        function funDivision() {
            var value = $('#drop1').val();
            arr[0] = value;
            ajaxLoadDropDown('#drop2', '/Home/Area?name=' + value);
        }

        function funDivision2() {
            var value = $('#drop2').val();
            ajaxLoadDropDown('#drop3', '/Home/Unit?name=' + value);
        }

        function funDivision3() {
            var value = $('#drop3').val();
            ajaxLoadDropDown('#drop4', '/Home/Section?name=' + value);
        }
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#btnView').on('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Home/Fetch/',
                    //datatype: "String",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                        //debugger;
                        var strHTML = '';
                        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
                            strHTML += '<table><tr><td>' + data[index].Version + '</td>&nbsp &nbsp<td>' + data[index].RequestedBy + '</td>&nbsp &nbsp<td>' + data[index].ReleaseTrigger + '</td>&nbsp &nbsp<td>' + data[index].ReleaseNotes + '</td></tr></table>';
                            $('#div1').html(strHTML);
                            //strHTML = '';
                        });

                        }         
                });
            });
```

We can use like this to print data in table format.